# Attaching Images to Questions

Tags: discussion

How do I attach (or paste in-line) a jpg to a question if I don't have a server to point the link to?

Comment: you can click the image button in the toolbar above the edit box. You can directly upload the image from your computer. There is a **very large** rectangular area which you can click and it will bring up an upload dialog box. Is your browser not displaying that rectangular area???

Comment: Too little rep (1) , perhaps.

Comment: Note that if you have less than 10 reputation points you cannot add images to the post. However, you can still upload it via the dialog AJN mentions, and  if you then remove the exclamation mark from the markdown code you will be allowed to post. A higher rep user can add it back in.

Comment: AJN: Cheers - it never crossed my mind that the box you point to should be used for this purpose.  I don't use www unless absolutely despatate.

Comment: @James -- while i'm rather fond of that question, it doesn't answer this one.  it simply suggests that the relevant information be placed in the faq,  and just now i tried to look in the faq to see if it had been added -- but i can't even find the faq!  (maybe i'm blind or otherwise impaired, but i don't see it anywhere, not even under the "help" list or on the "tour".)  so what am i missing?

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  I see that the body of your question discusses the faq.  However, your question title matches this OP's request.  Also, the highly-upvoted accepted answer to your question answers this OP's question.  ... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @James -- you're correct that the accepted answer does get to one point of the question, except that the interface has changed several times since that was written.  i guess what i'm complaining about is that something this important *should* really be in a faq, where it can be kept up to date, and that's a key part of what i was asking for.  i did accept the answer, because it told me how to accomplish what i needed at the time, but i still don't consider it ideal on account of the aging process.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I've updated my answer to reflect the new display/dialogue.

Comment: @Werner -- super!  thanks!  now i accept that this answers the present question with current info.